# USB powered off after boot with Power Mac G4 and Lubuntu

Tags: linux, mac, lubuntu, powerpc, g4

I have a Power Mac G4 that I'm trying to boot off of a USB drive, I can get it to load the kernel and ramdisk just fine, and it opens the display, but it shuts down the USB after loading kernel and ramdisk, preventing the kernel from checking the disk.

It says something like "Write not complete -28 != (some large number)"
And then it panics.

Are there any solutions to this?

Comment: Did you see this thread on [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/11128/how-do-i-make-my-1-5-ghz-powerbook-g4-boot-from-a-usb-stick)?

Comment: @JakeGould I have, that is how I got it to boot in the first place. My problem is after I type live into the lubuntu boot terminal, it will power off the USB and it will panic